# How can I make a function repeat until a specific key is pressed on python with pynput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, libraries, pynput

I want to do something like this

```
while True:
    fuction()
    function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed()
    if function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed==True:
        break
    break
```

Quick notes:

I'm using ios mojave.

i'm using python 3.9.

The "keyboard" python library isn't working for me.

I am using the pynput library but I would also be happy to use a different library if it works.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking a specific key with pynput in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693820/checking-a-specific-key-with-pynput-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard

def function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed():
    if keyboard.read_key()=="q":
        print(True)

while True:
    function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed()
    if function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed==True:
        break
    break
```

Comment: it is always helpful to explain your code to the person asking the question